# How to calculate sum of values based on month of year

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a dataset that I have created using a pivot table.

THe data looks like this:

```
product                 01-2010        02-2010          03-2010           04-2010        .....
product1               $234              $855                $839                $834               .....
product2               $855              $839                $834                $542               .....
product3               $343              $939                $884                $839               .....
```

What I want to do is use a lookup table to group ranges together

i.e. Q1 2010 = 01-2010, 02-2010, 03-2010

I want to rearrange the data to use a lookup table which identifies Q1 2010 as including 01-2010, 02-2010, 03-2010 and then display a new table:

```
product                 Q1-2010                                                               Q2-2010                                                                 .....
product1               SUM_OF(01-2010, 02-2010, 03-2010)          SUM_OF(04-2010, 05-2010, 06-2010)            .....
product2               SUM_OF(01-2010, 02-2010, 03-2010)          SUM_OF(04-2010, 05-2010, 06-2010)            .....
product3               SUM_OF(01-2010, 02-2010, 03-2010)          SUM_OF(04-2010, 05-2010, 06-2010)            .....
```

What is the best way of automating this?

Comment: It might be easier and more extensible to solve this problem against the source data as opposed to the aggregated PT result. Is that a possibility? Can you describe how the source data is organized?

Comment: I thought that and tried to add a new column to the Pivot data called HY Date as a calculated field on Month but the pivot wouldn't let me use it as a column...  The data is all stored in the spread-sheet itself so can be modifed quite easily...  Perhaps you're right - I'll add a new column in the source data and make it a vlookup to find the correct HY period

Comment: Would `SUMIF()` and/or `SUMIFS()` help you here?

Comment: Do you need a lookup?  ="Q" &CEILING(MONTH(C3)/3, 1) & "-" & YEAR(C3) will return the quarter in the format you want.  Excel should recognize 01-2010 as a date.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track: pivot refuses to take the column if it does not have a header.
So new column for month or quarter, add a header, and then pivot.